# Animation of div with photo work only one time

Tags: jquery, html

I have this piece of code that executes an animation with the two divs, but the animation of the div that contains the photo works only one time.  Where have I gone wrong?

JQuery Code

```
(function ($) {
    "use strict";

    jQuery("#bio-chiara").click(function () {
        $(function () {
            $("#foto-chiara").each(function (index) {

                if ($(this).css('top') == '0px') {
                    $(this).stop().animate({
                        bottom: '0px'
                    }, 1000);
                };
                if ($(this).css('bottom') == '0px') {
                    $(this).stop().animate({
                        top: '0px'
                    }, 1000);
                };
            });
        });
    });
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: Can you also include html code

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle sample?

Comment: You have Document ready (`$(function () {`) inside the click; which is wrong. Also `$("#foto-chiara").each()` means Duplicated IDs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is you are animating different properties without removing the other one.

try just animating the top property:

```
           if ($(this).css('top') == '0px') {
                $(this).stop().animate({
                    top: $(window).height() + 'px'
                }, 1000);
            } else  {
                $(this).stop().animate({
                    top: '0px'
                }, 1000);
            };
```

Or remove the property once the animation has completed:

```
            if ($(this).css('top') == '0px') {
                $(this).stop().animate({
                    bottom: '0px'
                }, 1000, function() {
                    $(this).css('top', '');
                });
            };
            if ($(this).css('bottom') == '0px') {
                $(this).stop().animate({
                    top: '0px'
                }, 1000, function() {
                    $(this).css('bottom', '');
                });
            };
```

and also remove the extra `$(function() {})` within your click event, it is not needed